# jQuery: Exclude the first and second columns that is VISIBLE

Tags: jquery, html-table

I have a simple task (so I thought) where I need to select all columns **EXCEPT** all ***INVISIBLE*** columns and the 1st and 2nd **VISIBLE** columns using jQuery, but it seems a lot harder than I thought.

Look at sample below

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Header1</th> <!--This column is hidden-->
            <th>Header2</th>
            <th>Header3</th>
            <th>Header4</th>
            <th>Header5</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Column1</td> <!--This column is hidden-->
            <td>Column2</td>
            <td>Column3</td>
            <td>Column4</td>
            <td>Column5</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
```

As you can see, header #1 and column #1 is hidden.

And I do the following to select using jQuery, it will select Column #3, #4 and #5. I want to select Column #4 and #5.

```
//Attempt #1
var $ths = $tbl.find('thead > tr > th:not(:hidden, :nth-child(1), :nth-child(2))');
var $tds = $tbl.find('tbody > tr > td:not(:hidden, :nth-child(1), :nth-child(2))');

//Attempt #2
var $ths = $tbl.find('thead > tr > th:not(:hidden):not(:nth-child(1), :nth-child(2))');
var $tds = $tbl.find('tbody > tr > td:not(:hidden):not(:nth-child(1), :nth-child(2))');
```

The quick workaround for me is to SELECT all VISIBLE columns then exclude the first 2 columns into new array. I need to do this way because the hidden column can be in the middle (user is allow to hide/show columns - eg. **Column #1** and **Column #3** are hidden columns, therefore, the selection must return ONLY **Column #5** as **Column #2** and **Column #4** become the 1st and 2nd columns).

This is my workaround

```
var $ths = $tbl.find('thead > tr > th:not(:hidden)').slice(2);
var $tds = $tbl.find('tbody > tr > td:not(:hidden)').slice(2);
```

Any idea on how to do it on a simple a jQuery selector?

Thanks...

Comment: Do you really mean to have `<tr>` before each column?

Comment: lol... you are right... sorry... I've changed the html code :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`:visible:lt(2)` matches the first 2 visible columns, so putting that inside `:not` excludes them.

```js
var $ths = $("thead > tr > th:not(:visible:lt(2))");
var $tds = $("tbody > tr > td:not(:visible:lt(2))");

console.log($ths.map((i, el) => el.innerHTML).get(), $tds.map((i, el) => el.innerHTML).get());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="display: none">Header1</th><!--This column is hidden-->
      <th>Header2</th>
      <th>Header3</th>
      <th>Header4</th>
      <th>Header5</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="display: none">Column1</td><!--This column is hidden-->
      <td>Column2</td>
      <td>Column3</td>
      <td>Column4</td>
      <td>Column5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="display: none">Column1</td><!--This column is hidden-->
      <td>Row 2 Column2</td>
      <td>Row 2 Column3</td>
      <td>Row 2 Column4</td>
      <td>Row 2 Column5</td>
    </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: This is almost perfect! But it also includes the hidden columns :(  I've created the JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/9vLadrqb/

Comment: You said to exclude the first two visible columns. Nothing about excluding hidden columns.

Comment: If you only want visible columns, except the first two, it's even easier: `:visible:gt{1)`

Comment: my apology, I have updated question... I'll try your recommendation... thanks

Comment: Just realized that this doesn't work for multiple rows in the body. `:lt` and `:gt` are not counting within rows.

Comment: This will probably require a `.each()` loop to loop over rows.

Comment: I am hoping for the one liner... lol... Otherwise, I'll stick with my workaround...